# What is the meaning of "Not much something than yours"?

Tags: american-english, questions, spoken-english

For example, if a guy tells another that "My hair is not much spikier than yours". Does it mean:

1. Both their hairs are about the same spikiness
2. The first guy's hair is little less spikier

I know the meaning of the sentence without adding the "much" but adding it kinda confuses me.

Comment: 1: *X is better than Y* unambiguously asserts that X is the best - perhaps "only just", but perhaps by a huge margin. 2: *X is **not** better than Y* simply ***denies*** that preceding assertion (perhaps Y is best, or perhaps they're equally good; we're not told). But idiomatically 3: *X is **not much** better than Y* isn't quite the same as #2, because it would ***never*** be used if Y was actually best. That last version is only used when X is definitely better - ***but not by much*** (they're both ***nearly*** as good as each other, but X is at least a ***little*** better than Y).

Answer (score 1):

"My hair is **not much** spikier than yours" concedes that my hair **is** spikier than yours, but claims it isn't **much** spikier.
That amounts to "My hair is **only a little bit spikier** than yours."

Preceding the word "much", the negation "not" applies to it. It doesn't apply to "spikier".

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a response to "Your hair is spiky"

A bit like "You're ugly"  "Not much more ugly than you"